# Android EditText - changing new input style

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, richtext

I'm trying to write a simple rich text editor application. I would like to be able to press different "style" buttons (e.g. bold, italic) to make all further inputs have that style, just like I could in an office application.

I was thinking I could have every new character be selected in a SpannableString and then change its style, but I don't know how I could do that. I tried setting an OnTextChangedListener but I later found out it's probably not suitable for what I want to do. If I knew how to listen for all new inputs I could probably figure something out, but I can't find anything that does that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check this [new library](https://github.com/noecivitillo/ToolText) that i just uploaded, hope it's helps!

Comment: It looks really nice, I'll definitely try it. I already managed to do what I needed but since it was for a university project I didn't go much beyond the basics, maybe I'll expand it just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this eBay Open Source Android project called the [Mildly Rich Text Editor](https://github.com/eBay/Mildly-Rich-Text-Editor) that I am currently working on. It is a rich text editing library adapted from Droid Writer that makes use of spans. It can also be imported as a library in your application.

There is a demo app included in the repository that you can build and try out.

Note that there are some limitations noted in the "issues" section of the GitHub repository (e.g. it does not currently work with custom keyboards). Please also feel free to contribute.

Comment: From your example I managed to make some progress using a textwatcher (my previous attempts failed because I didn't quite understand how to use it) but I had some consistency issues, typing very quickly seems to result in the watcher "missing" a letter here and there. Do you know an easy solution for that or should I open another question?Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

you can get help with https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

you can use onkeypress or onclick event and check for that key with ASCII values of keys